# Convert list of str tuples into list of int tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which I would like to import into a dictionary. Those tuples consist of two strings. I would like to convert those tuples into integers. i.e

```
myList = ['0,1', '0,2', '0,3']
```

The resulting list should be:

```
resList = [(0,1), (0,2), (0,3)]
```

I have tried using:

```
list(map(int, myList))
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `eval` function to get the tuples, like this. Works in both python2, and python3.

```
>>> myList = ['0,1', '0,2', '0,3']
>>> list(map(eval, myList))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You also need to split your strings by `','`.

```
>>> [tuple(map(int, s.split(','))) for s in myList]                                                                               
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

Another option is to use the `csv` module.

```
>>> import csv                                                                                                                    
>>> list(csv.reader(myList))                                                                                                      
[['0', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['0', '3']]
>>> [tuple(map(int, row)) for row in csv.reader(myList)]                                                                          
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

If it's not terribly important the the inner elements of the result are tuples and that they are of type `int`, we can simplify the `csv` solution to

```
>>> list(csv.reader(myList, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC))                                                                        
[[0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 3.0]]
```

---

**~edit~**

[thelogicalkoan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052465/3620003) reminded me of `ast.literal_eval` which provides the most elegant (and safe) solution here.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval                                                                                                  
>>> [literal_eval(x) for x in myList]                                                                                             
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is too powerful for this use case. In particular, it will happily parse lines with other valid python structures in them. I would argue it is marginally less safe than splitting and parsing via `int`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use `ast.literal_eval` (instead of `eval` which can be considered unsafe):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval('0,1')
(0, 1)
```

So, you can do:

```
>>> my_list = ['0,1', '0,2', '0,3']
>>> result = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in my_list]
>>> result
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

[str.partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) can be used to do this.

```
>>> [(int(x), int(y)) for x, _, y in (z.partition(',') for z in myList)]
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```

The generator expression `(z.partition(',') for z in myList)` produces the output of `str.partition` on each element of the list, and then we call `int` on the parts that we require.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different option:

```
myList = ['0,1', '0,2', '0,3']

def tSet(list): 
    return tuple([int(i) for i in list])

resList  = [tSet(i.split(",")) for i in myList]

print(resList) #Output: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3)]
```